# why are transitions not working properly - safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions

I have a site which relies heavily on 'transitions'. This works perfectly on Chrome, FireFox and Opera. It just really wigs out on Safari - particularly when you click on 'projects' - the 'body' doesn't properly change colour. Am I including the right code?

This is one element for example:

```
    .line-bottom {
      transition: 1.3s;
     -webkit-transition: 1.3s;
    }
```

Link to page (which is a WIP, you will get stuck on mind section): http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/

Comment: Looks like a repaint bug. When you open Safari's dev tools, the background changes properly. I think it's a bug in Safari as I've had similar problems before. You could look into forcing a repaint on that click event although that might cause some performance issues. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Oh right okay. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

In safari browser you can try this

.line_bottom{
-webkit-transition:1.3s
}

You have to use browser prefix in safari

Comment: Can you try this add transition-property:all after webkit-tranision